# Upload and download file to Amazon from android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload file to amazon from my android application.
I have downloaded AWS SDK and added to build path of my project.
Now i want to upload file to my bucket.which is already created.
SO how can i upload file, i am not getting any proper solution to it.

Please help and provide your suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at our Getting Started Guide for S3 and looking into the TransferManager which is meant as a high level utility for easily handling uploads/downloads

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Comment: i have done upload and download part using s3 but i want to upload using cloud front api.I have completed download part using clud front.any idea?

Comment: Can you explain a little further?  CloudFront does not have a download API, it is a CDN which when populated will be the source people will download from.  If you are just trying to download/upload images from a mobile app S3 is likely what you are looking for.  If you have some content you expect to be accessed very frequently and you want to host it on a CDN then it may be best to do that from a server or the CloudFront console.